# time saved to save string variables vs hardcoding

Tags: java, string, optimization, execution-time

I have tried searching the web/stackoverflow for this but can not find an answer.  I am not sure if it is because it is so obvious or such a negligible difference.

My basic question is... which is better performance/by how much?

```
String attacker = pairs.getKey();
mobInstanceMap.replace(attacker, 0);
```

vs:

```
mobInstanceMap.replace(pairs.getKey(), 0);
```

I like the first for readability, but I have been developing a MMORPG with which I need to be quite careful with performance.  I tried to do an experiment below, but figured I would ask the gurus since it was hard for me to extrapolate.  I flipped which one runs as I found out that when running both(one after the other) the second ran much better(probably due to JVM optimization).

Sorry if this has been asked and answered... or is obvious, but I searched and did not find anything(maybe I don't know what to search for).  I am not only wondering for 'saving off' strings, but other variables also.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long hardcodeTotal = 0;
    long saveTotal = 0;

//      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
//          saveTotal += checkRunTimeSaveString();
//      }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        hardcodeTotal += checkRunTimeHardcodeString();
    }

    System.out.println("hardcodeTotal: " + hardcodeTotal/100.0 + "\t" + "saveTotal: " + saveTotal/100.0);

}

private static long checkRunTimeSaveString(){
    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = mobInstanceMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) { //to update the AttackingMap when entity(attackee) moves
        Entry<String, Integer> pairs = it.next();
        String attacker = pairs.getKey();
        mobInstanceMap.replace(attacker, 0);
    }

    return(System.nanoTime() - StartTime);
}

private static long checkRunTimeHardcodeString(){
    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = mobInstanceMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) { //to update the AttackingMap when entity(attackee) moves
        Entry<String, Integer> pairs = it.next();
        mobInstanceMap.replace(pairs.getKey(), 0);
    }

    return(System.nanoTime() - StartTime);
}
```

Comment: regardless of performace and of the code you posted, I would always go for first choice, as you said it more readable and add to it it's better maintainable. Just imagine you are debugging your application, with second choice you would not easily see the value of `pairs.getKey()` unless you have a watch on it, witch is less confortable than just pointing with the mouse over the variable `attacker`. That's just for development phase. Now you code is in production and you get a stack trace with `NPE` on that line, now what is the cause? `mobInstanceMap` or `pairs`?

Comment: agreed.  Thanks mate, appreciate the reassurance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all likelihood, the intermediate assigment will be optimized away by the JVM, and they will have exactly the same performance.

In either case, the possible performance hits for these things are hardly ever noticeable. You shouldn't worry about performance unless in extreme circumstances. Always opt for readability.

It should also be added that the type of micro-benchmarking you have in your code above is incredibly hard to get reliable measurements from. Too many factors out of your control (internal JVM optimizations, JVM warmup etc etc) are involved to get an accurate measurement of the exact thing you want to test.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to make sure.  My thoughts exactly.  Glad to have the confirmation :D

Answer (score 1):

you could profile both implementations with a tool like JVisualVM to see the exact difference. In case you want to test with high volume you could use a tool like Contiperf   http://databene.org/contiperf And then share the results for all of us :)

Comment: great now my TODO:: list has grown!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Keppil that the performance is probably exactly the same. If there is a slight difference, and if you care about such a small improvement in performance, then you probably shouldn't be using Java in the first place.